# App closes with no crash alert

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app on the AppStore and I updated it two days ago. On all the phones I checked it works good, but I do get complaints from some users that the app closes with no crash alert, right after the opening.
I checked the crash report on Xcode and found this error:`\UIKit: __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 556` and saw it's something with the UI, but I'm not sure that's the reason for the app closing because I didn't change the UI between the versions and again it's not a crash...
and I have no exit(0) on the code.

I'm sorry there's no code, nothing has changed at the app opening between the versions (I just added a QR class that users can open on a button click).

Does someone know about a possible reason the app closes (or go immediately
to the background) with no alerts?

Edit: I just had a phone with this problem. When I install the app directly from my computer the app works, when I install from the store it closes...

Edit2:
Thanks to @Cy-4AH, here is the logcat:

```
kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[7827] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7E2AA7B7-E2B2-4B2A-A362-BF95D6DFF594 (sandbox)
 <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
 <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 7827
 <Warning>: Attempt to read info_array in pid 7827 failed, address was 120045fe8
 <Warning>: Attempt to read info_array in pid 7827 failed, address was 120045fe8
 <Warning>: Attempt to read info_array in pid 7827 failed, address was 120045fe8
 <Warning>: Attempt to read info_array in pid 7827 failed, address was 120045fe8
 <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process TmcSystemsApp[7827]
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.tmc-systems.TmcSystemsApp[0x578a][7827]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
 <Error>: Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs.
 <Error>: Could not save crash report to disk!
 <Error>: Incident Identifier: DBBCA5F0-062B-4430-AFDA-03E4218DE37F
 <Error>: CrashReporter Key:   36ec2d0341c8d9e6a53e387d034dfa76962801d5
 <Error>: Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
 <Error>: Process:             TmcSystemsApp [7827]
 <Error>: Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9C394EDA-BC3A-4AE3-AD6F-E9D9A42D5F37/TmcSystemsApp.app/TmcSystemsApp
 <Error>: Identifier:          TmcSystemsApp
 <Error>: Version:             ???
 <Error>: Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
 <Error>: Parent Process:      launchd [1]
 <Error>: Date/Time:           2016-08-17 12:28:38.078 +0300
 <Error>: Launch Time:         2016-08-17 12:28:38.043 +0300
 <Error>: OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
 <Error>: Report Version:      105
 <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
 <Error>: Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000120019088
 <Error>: Triggered by Thread:  0
 <Error>: Dyld Error Message:
 <Error>:   Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ContactsUI.framework/ContactsUI
 <Error>:   Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9C394EDA-BC3A-4AE3-AD6F-E9D9A42D5F37/TmcSystemsApp.app/TmcSystemsApp
 <Error>:   Reason: image not found
 <Error>:   Dyld Version: 353.12
 <Error>: Binary Images:
 <Error>: 0x120018000 - 0x12003ffff dyld arm64  <dddc36a8e70636f7a9fea757477bf90b> /usr/lib/dyld
SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.tmc-systems.TmcSystemsApp[0x578a]' crashed.
```

Comment: Try to found what's special for crashing devices. Maybe they use older iOS version.
Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237571/random-uisearchdisplaycontroller-crash-ios-7

Comment: Thanks but It's not about the versions, it works good on 4s but happens on 6s (on another 6s it works good too).

Comment: Did you add resources to the project between the last and this update? I've had issues with this in the past because I added a resource to my dev target, but that doesn't automatically add it to all targets so my store target didn't have it in the "copy bundle resources" section of build phases. Trying to access a resource that is not copied into the bundle causes the exact behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Kevin I added frameworks to my project, I'll try to check that too, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application links to a framework (`ContactsUI`) that was added in iOS 9, and your app is launching on an iOS 8.4.1 devices. When dyld tries to resolve the framework it can't find it and fails.

You either need to weak link the ContactsUI framework and check for its presence before using anything from it, or change your min deployment target to iOS 9.0

Comment: Thanks, it was the contactsUI framework. But if the problem is versions, how did it work on iPhone 4s with version 8.4?

Answer (score 2):

If it's not generate crash reports, then yours application is closed by system.  It can happen by several reasons: too much allocated memory, didStartApplication is too long. Try to find out in console log why yours application was closed by system.

Comment: Thanks, I can't check that in console log because when I install it from my computer it works, but I'll try to check that anyway.

Comment: @MorZa Install from appstore and look in console. What the problem?

Comment: Well the main problem now is that all the phones I have are working, I had a  phone with this problem for a few minutes from a user :) I'll try to check that when I'll have one again. Thanks.

Comment: When I run the app from App Store the app closes but I see nothing in the console...

Comment: @MorZa looks like you are looking in wrong console. There is should be dozens messages anyway.

Comment: I downloaded an app called "Console" from app store, it tracks all the messages.

Comment: @MorZa In Xcode menu: Window->Devices select yours device and you will see console.

Comment: Nice, thanks, i go to "view device logs" and see a list of crashes there, but still don't see this current app closing, maybe because it's not a crash(?). In the meantime I work with this app and it helps but nice to know this option.

Comment: @MorZa there is button with △ symbol at the bottom, under installed apps list. If you press that, you will see console.

Answer (score 0):

iOS magically kills an app [if `applicationDidFinishLaunching` takes to long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169470/does-the-iphone-timeout-if-a-function-takes-too-long-to-execute), so I would recommend looking in that function and moving whatever lines you added for QR code support into some different function (e.g. if this were my code, maybe I would put it into the view controller's `viewDidLoad` function, even behind a `dispatch_async` block).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it takes less than a second. And I don't understand why to move it to viewDidLoad instead of a button click, on a button click it doesn't take time at all, or am I missing something? Please see my edit.

Comment: You can also do what you need on a button click too. The point is to keep your 'applicationDidFiinishLaunching' method as lean as possible., so the built in timeouts in iOS won't magically fire.